# How can i notify by computer when data is not properly inserted in php mysql

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am creating salary payroll software. Currently I have faced a problem. When i transfer one month salary to next month of an all employee, Light is cut off and system is off and it only update 17 record out of 100 employee. So how can i get alert() message when ever light off, network error so that i can again update left fields.

For inserting records i have used javascript, ajax and php.

I want alert message whenever data is not properly inserted.

Thanks 
Kapil

Comment: Get a better electricity supplier?

Comment: How do you know that only 17 records have been updated? If that is clear, you can check for that and only process the records that have not been updated yet.

Comment: I can check that in db but client will not check that. This software is run in Indian government offices. and some of employee are very lazy.

Comment: We need to cover all problems.

Comment: Any one have idea about how to do that